# Help Installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

Whenever I boot Ubuntu on my USB, it starts fine. But when I try to select the partition that I want it to go in, it says "no root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu". I emptied the partition beforehand and it has more than enough space. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer.  Assume you are installing from the usb stick. When you reach the screen that shows all the install options, choose "something else". This allows you to choose/configure partitions. You will need to have at least 3 partitions: 1 for swap; 1 for root "/"; 1 for home "/home". I use this method to ensure the program files are segregated from my data: root for programs; home for data. hope this helps you.

Comment: How much should I allocate to each partition? I had about 500 GB that I set aside for linux. Should I just split that up evenly or what?

Comment: Size is per user needs.  I chose 40GB for "/" , 10GB for "swap", the rest allocated to "/home".   This is plenty for root and swap.  Do not go lower than 5GB for swap.  IF you want to recover your system to say 2 prior upgrades, you may want to increase "/" to say 60GB.  I find 40GB to be plenty for the current and prior upgrade. To ensure I have space for the next upgrade, I run autoremove and autoclean before each upgrade to remove redundant pkgs.  hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is more than note worthy to add info concerning Legacy BIOS, EFI and UEFI machines especially when the HDD is a GPT type and since HDD sizes are pushing the limits of these Old boot modes. Here is at least one decent wiki more to the point: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes  It is a common mistake to mix these GPT disks and boot modes leaving the inexperienced DIY with a non-bootable machine and believing Linux is the cause.  For future readers of Eli's question seeking help that info may be of great use.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI covers more. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Use LVM with new installation** in case you are looking for default partition scheme:
1) Root(/) and 2) Swap
Or
choose 
**Something else**. This will let you choose the partitions like /home, /usr, /, /var etc...

My suggestion whichever option you choose -it's always best to stick to / and swap - only two partitions if you are new to Linux.
Let's say you just choose to have two partitions - / and swap. Highlight '/' to install Linux into that.

Comment: correct.  Ubuntu will install into "/" by default: this is the whole purpose of creating the root partition.